# Emulating an embedded Android device with qemu

Tags: android, embedded-linux, qemu, u-boot

I have an embedded device running Android 4.4. I would like to try to emulate this device using Qemu.
I have root access via ADB to this device and have created a dump of all partitions (including several ext4 filesystems) from the emmc. So I have several .raw files ("mmcblk0boot0.raw, mmblk0p1 ... p14, mmblk0rpmb.raw"). The bootloader is U-Boot. Furthermore I found the files "bootarea.img, system.img and recovery.img" in the file system.
Since qemu is new to me, I am not sure how to proceed. Does anyone have any advice for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have a look at  Google's [Android Emulator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/emu-master-dev/README.md), which is a version of Qemu customized by Google for Android ? this may be a shortest path to achieving your goal than spending a lot of time re-doing what Google already successfully did.

Comment: I know the Android Emulator but I am not sure if it will work with my partition dumps. But I will give it a try